# Displaying horizontal line between rows by dragging over in WPF Data Grid or Xceed Data Grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, xceed

I am looking for some possibility in WPF how to show horizontal line between rows by dragging over in WPF Data Grid or Xceed Data Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should must set the RowStyle property, and then listen for the events `DragEnter` and `DragLeave`, for instance:

The datagrid code:

`<DataGrid  RowStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridRowStyle1}"/>`

This is a a copy of the wpf's `DataGrid` row style that already has the two triggers (for `DragEnter` and `DragLeave`):

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="2,0,0,0" Text="!" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Border x:Name="DGR_Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}"/>
                            <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragDrop.DragEnter"/>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DragDrop.DragLeave"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The only thing that you need to do is add the `Line` or `Rectange` that you want to show, set the `Visibility` on `Collapsed` or `Hidden`, and then in the triggers change the line's visibility value.
Hope this answer may helps to you, and give you an idea to make it work, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Also you may use this drag&drop library: Drag and Drop in WPF ([I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF) and [II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43702/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF-Part-II)). You can see the code, they use an adorner for drawing a line between the elements to drop.